# What topics should be discussed here?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are many people who don't seem to like the quality of questions that are on this site, and there's probably a half dozen questions on Meta about should something be on topic for this site. Perhaps it's easier to just ask in one place. What should this site be all about? I don't want to hear about things it shouldn't be about, only about what it should be about. Please limit your ideas to no more than a few related subjects per answer, feel free to answer more than one if you'd like. Please vote up the answers you would like to see included, and down the answers you would like to see removed. Add comments if you think you can add to the discussion of a particular topic

Comment: Calling it "Grumbling" doesn't help your case. Please understand that this site *will* be closed down if the Stack Exchange employees think this site isn't working, and the people more experienced with Stack Exchange are the very ones who can help the most.

Comment: I'll make it a bit nicer, but the point of this thread is to try and figure out what this site should be about. There are definitely some nuggets in the dirt of this SE site, and I'm just trying to figure out what we all agree are the nuggets, so we can keep them and keep the site as a whole functioning.

Comment: The reason why the information is hard to find on Meta is that there is no consensus yet. I recommend participating on Meta threads on a specific topic (by voting on answers you like, or adding your own if you have new arguments to contribute).

Answer (score 3):

List of books that feature a particular technology, theme, or idea ([Books or movies dealing with the early colonization of Mars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/844/books-or-movies-dealing-with-the-early-colonization-of-mars), [What movies feature time travel as a central plot device?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/820/what-movies-feature-time-travel-as-a-central-plot-device))

Answer (score 3):

Obscure triva requests ([What was Shepard Book's past in Firefly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-was-shepard-books-past-in-firefly), [In the Dune series, why are they not using computers and programming related technologies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164/in-the-dune-series-why-are-they-not-using-computers-and-programming-related-tech))

Answer (score 1):

How Sci-fi and reality mix (IE, [What FTL drives might be possible](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/654/what-ftl-drives-in-science-fiction-are-the-most-scientifically-plausible/661#661), [Could electronics be developed by water-based life forms? What would they be like?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/257/could-electronics-be-developed-by-water-based-life-forms-what-would-they-be-like))

Answer (score 1):

Questions gathering common related sci-fi technologies into one question ([What are the different types and classes of FTL engines?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/705/what-are-the-different-types-and-classes-of-ftl-engines))

Answer (score 0):

Topics relating Sci-fi books to movies ([When we will see Pierson's Puppeteers on the big screen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-we-will-see-piersons-puppeteers-on-the-big-screen), [What are the *Least* faithful movie adaptation of a sci-fi book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/705/what-are-the-different-types-and-classes-of-ftl-engines))

Comment: @Dori Then vote it down. I'm fine with that.